# RSpec verbose error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run any RSpec test that fails, I get many lines of messages that I don't really understand.

For instance, suppose I run:

```
expect(true).to be_false
```

Then my console gets cluttered with messages beginning with `#`

```
Failures:

  1) Some test
     Failure/Error: expect(true).to be_false
     expected true to respond to `false?`

 # ./spec/controllers/wing_relationships_controller_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
 # /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The error messages always vary, and sometimes they are extremely long.

When I run many tests, it gets hard to read the results. I would like to get rid of those. Any suggestions? I already turned off `--warning` in RSpec

Answer (score 0):

It's better find out where the errors come from and fix the leaky specs rather the ignoring the errors.

If you are not interested in doing it for some reason then you can always use:
You use a simple trick if you really want to:

```
rspec 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I would like to fix the errors, but the error messages are incomprehensible. It seems like they just list a bunch of paths with no instructions. Any way to fix this?

Comment: It's hard without much context. But try isolating the test that is failing, run just the expectation you're interested in and not the whole test suite. Try to understand if you are requiring the right dependencies to your file, and turn the warnings on again. If you're still stuck, try posting a gist of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1237

To remove the gems from the output, it's one line of config:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns << %r{/gems/}
end
```

Or, if you want to only filter out particular gems from your backtraces:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_gems_from_backtrace "rack", "rack-test", "capybara"
end
```